# Save a selection in QGIS and keep the alias of field names?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, alias

I am trying to save selected features into a new shapefile using QGIS 10.2.  The new file does not contain the aliases for the field names.

Is there a way to maintain the aliases in new files?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the exact answer you want it wouldnt be exporting the aliases directly but you can do this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the field aliases, when you save the style of your original layer to .qml and then load it to your new layer:

Open the layer properties: At the bottom of the window, there is a Style button (next to Help).

Save from orginal:

**Properties -> Style (dropdown) -> Save Style -> QGIS Layer Style File**

Load to new layer:

**Properties -> Style (dropdown) -> Load Style ...**

Of course, this will transfer also all other styles and settings of the original layer.