# setAlias doesn't work on geopackage

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

I'm trying to add multiple fields to a geopackage layer and set their aliases at the same time. It is working on a temp layer but not on the geopackage, why?

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
p = lyr.dataProvider()
fl =    [['grtr_spr_t',QVariant.Int,'test'], #name, type, alias
        ['grtr_spr_g',QVariant.Int, 'test2'],
        ['grtr_spr_l',QVariant.Int, 'test3']]

fieldlist = [QgsField(f[0], f[1]) for f in fl] #Create a list of QgsFields

for e, data in enumerate(fl):
    fieldlist[e].setAlias(data[2]) #Set the aliases of them

#[f.alias() for f in fieldlist]
#['test', 'test2', 'test3'] #They are set

p.addAttributes(fieldlist)
lyr.updateFields()
```

[image]

Comment: At least the method is supported also for GeoPackage layers because it is possible to set the alias manually from the UI as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315979/adding-field-aliases-from-csv-in-qgis.

Comment: Yes I have also managed to set it manually. Maybe my QGIS or geopackage is broken

Comment: If you can set alias to the same geopackage manually then how could it be broken? And as far as I understand the alias is not even stored into GeoPackage data file.

Comment: Is the code working for you on a gpkg?

Comment: No, it does not. But I can add an alias by continuing with `lyr.setFieldAlias(1,'test')` and then I see `lyr.attributeAliases() {'fid': '', 'grtr_spr_t': 'test'}`. "test" shows also when I open the attribute table from TOC.

Comment: I think I found a way using: `[lyr.setFieldAlias(n, a) for n, a in enumerate(['TEST1','TEST2','TEST3'], 1)]`. I will restructure the code.

Comment: I just need to save it in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('startpunkt')[0]
p = layer.dataProvider()

fieldlist =     [["grtrsprt", "P", QVariant.Int],
                 ["grtrsprg", "S", QVariant.Int],
                 ["grtrsprl", "D", QVariant.Int],
                 ["grtrgrpt", "P", QVariant.Int],
                 ["grtrgrpg", "S", QVariant.Int],
                 ["grtrgrpl", "D", QVariant.Int]]

#Add the fields
newfieldlist = [QgsField(f[0], f[2]) for f in fieldlist]
p.addAttributes(faltlista)
layer.updateFields()

#Set the aliases
fieldindexes = [[layer.fields().indexFromName(f[0]), f[1]] for f in fieldlist] #List of lists of field index and alias
[layer.setFieldAlias(i[0], i[1]) for i in fieldindexes]
```

[image]